# Change the line to JSON

Tags: json

I downloaded a script. called tagator. 
But now i want to change the autocomplete: line to a JSON line so that i can get the names of the database.

```
    <script>
    $(function () {
        $('#activate_tagator').click(function () {
            if ($('#inputTagator').data('tagator') === undefined) {
                $('#inputTagator').tagator({
                    autocomplete: ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth', 'seventh', 'eighth', 'ninth', 'tenth']
                });
                $('#activate_tagator').val('destroy tagator');
            } else {
                $('#inputTagator').tagator('destroy');
                $('#activate_tagator').val('activate tagator');
            }
        });
        $('#activate_tagator').trigger('click');
    });
</script>
```

How do I get that to a JSON line?

php file

```
<?php
define('DB_USER', 'XXX');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'XXX');
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'XXX');

if (!$db = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)) {
die($db->connect_errno.' - '.$db->connect_error);
}
$arr = array();
if (!empty($_POST['tagwords'])) {
$tagwords = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['tagwords']);
$sql = "SELECT id, tag_name FROM tags WHERE tag_name LIKE '%".$tagwords."%'";
$result = $db->query($sql) or die($mysqli->error);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {
        $arr[] = array('id' => $obj->id, 'tag_name' => $obj->tag_name);
    }
  }
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: So you want autocomplete to be initialized from values in a database?

Comment: yes so that the values / tag name to be loaded. Sorry for my bad english

Comment: this might help: http://jsfiddle.net/216j50eL/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, I still do not understand how I get particularly loaded the values / tag. I have edited my question above. Because JSON / jquery are not my strong points

Comment: I think want you are looking for is an [AJAX call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming))?

Comment: If it works whit ajax?